# How to encrypt a String with a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to encrypt a string inside my Firebase Cloud Function. I would love to use SHA-256 or AES-256 for this. However I didn't find the right approach yet.

```
exports.myfunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {  
  const someString = "Hello World!"
  const encryptedString = // How could I do this here?

  return encryptedString
})
```

Therefore any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Cloud Functions are fairly standard Node.js scripts, so you should be able to search for your preferred encryption algorithm + node.js to get some answers/tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good choice for this is probably the crypto module. It provides cryptographic functionality that includes a set of wrappers for OpenSSL's hash, HMAC, cipher, decipher, sign, and verify functions.

You can use `crypto.createHash(algorithm\[, options\])` to encrypt a string. Check the [documentation on this function](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options).

This is the final solution:

```
// Use `require('crypto')` to access this module.
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.myfunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {  
  const secret = 'Hello World!';
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')
                   .update(pwd)
                   .digest('base64'); // you can also use 'hex'
  return hash
})
```

Also take a look at the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto).

Answer (score 1):

Install crypto-js with this command.
`npm install crypto-js`

Then import it and encode your string.

```
const AES = require("crypto-js/aes");
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

exports.myfunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {  
  const someString = "Hello World!";
  const encryptedString = SHA256(someString);
  // or
  const encryptedString = AES(someString);

  return encryptedString;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the [Google Tink Library](https://github.com/google/tink)

> A multi-language, cross-platform library that provides cryptographic APIs that are secure, easy to use correctly, and hard(er) to misuse.